# Concept: ManageSellOffer didn't update but instead create a new offer

Tags: stellar-laboratory, manageofferoperation, offer, dex

I read the documentation and it says that by providing the original `offerId` of a `ManageSellOffer`, one is able to change its price. But after I tried it out, I found that it creates another offer and the original offer is still there.

So... what can we really update? amount or?

P.S. Delete works as described in the documentation.

Comment: Please provide your source code or detailed steps needed to reproduce the problem. I can say for sure that it's possible to change an offer amount and price using the `ManageSellOffer` operation

Comment: I tried to reproduce using the laboraty (from the tag) and couldn't reproduce this issue.